# has_many through using wrong column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a simply rails application. It contains two models. Employee and EmployeeManager. I Basically want an Employee to have one or more Managers (other Employees) and I wish to be able to query these as you would expect.

Here's my Employee:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :employee_managers
  has_many :managers,  through: :employee_managers
  has_many :employees, through: :employee_managers
end
```

And the manager model:

```
class EmployeeManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :employee_id, :manager_id
  belongs_to :employee, foreign_key: "employee_id"                                                                                                        
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "manager_id"
end
```

This looks OK to me, however when I go to query employees and managers off an Employee Rails is using the same column (employee_id=X):

irb(main):008:0> Employee.first 
Employee Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" LIMIT 1
=> #
irb(main):009:0> Employee.first.managers
Employee Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" LIMIT 1   Employee Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" INNER JOIN "employee_managers" ON "employees"."id" = "employee_managers"."manager_id" WHERE "employee_managers"."employee_id" = 1
=> []
irb(main):010:0> Employee.first.employees
Employee Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" LIMIT 1   Employee Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" INNER JOIN "employee_managers" ON "employees"."id" = "employee_managers"."employee_id" **WHERE "employee_managers"."employee_id" = 1**
=> []

How do I fix this last query? It should be using manager_id not employee_id!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the foreign_key in the Employee model, and add and inverse relation (its the same Model)

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_managers
  has_many :managers, through: :employee_managers

  has_many :manager_employees, :class_name => "EmployeeManager", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
  has_many :employees, through: :manager_employees, :source => "Employee"
end
```

**Other changes:**

You don't need `attr_accessible :name` or `attr_accessible :employee_id, :manager_id`. Just add attr_accessible for fields that are not in the database.

Comment: That makes no difference I'm afraid

Comment: I think the foreign_keys where in the wrong order. I updated the answer. Please check

Comment: still no difference

Comment: Sorry. I was in a hurry and wrong :). This should work.

Comment: I'm presuming through: :manager_employees should be through: :_manager_employees, in any case no difference still I'm afraid.

Comment: My mistake. remove the '_' (I also did it in the answer). I had also left a previous mistake in the answer, in the `has_many :managers`. The foreign_key was wrong. Now this must work